# Problema de ubicación en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, app

tengo un problema con mi aplicación en Android Studio. En resumen, quiero que muestre la ubicación actual, incluidas la latitud y la altitud. La cosa es que al momento de abrir la actividad no me muestra dichos datos, sino se queda congelada en "Localización agregada...", dentro del OnCreate. No tengo idea de que puede estar mal. También he intentado usar el emulador de Android que tiene Android Studio, pero hace poco me enteré de que la ubicación de dicho dispositivo no es la actual, así que no me serviría de mucho. Este es el código:

```
public class Coordenadas extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LocationManager ubicacion;
    TextView mensaje1;
    TextView mensaje2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.coordenadas);

        mensaje1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mensaje1);
        mensaje2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mensaje2);

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Localizacion Local = new Localizacion();
        Local.setUbicacion(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) Local);
        mensaje1.setText("Localización Agregada...");
        mensaje2.setText("");
    }

    public void serLocalizacion(Location loc) {
        if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                    mensaje2.setText("Mi ubicacion es: \n" + DirCalle.getAddressLine(0));

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
        Coordenadas ubicacion;

        public Coordenadas getUbicacion() {
            return ubicacion;

        }

        public void setUbicacion(Coordenadas ubicacion) {
            this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
        }


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
            String Text = "Su ubicación actual es:" + "\n lat=" + loc.getLatitude() + "\n long=" + loc.getLongitude();
            mensaje1.setText(Text);
            this.ubicacion.serLocalizacion(loc);

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            mensaje1.setText("gps desativado");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            mensaje1.setText("gps activado");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

    }

}
```

Permisos del archivo Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Archivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Coordenadas">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mensaje1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="."
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColorHint="#757575" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mensaje2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="."
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColorHint="#757575" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mensaje3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="ㅤ⠀ㅤ"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColorHint="#757575"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mensaje4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="ㅤ⠀ㅤ"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColorHint="#757575" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Actualice el código, quizas le sirva a alguien:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    Button btn_ubi;
    TextView txt_ubi;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_ubi = findViewById(R.id.txt_ubi);
        btn_ubi = findViewById(R.id.btn_ubi);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, 100);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            }, 100);
        }


        btn_ubi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getLocation();
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getLocation() {

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, MainActivity.this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

            txt_ubi.setText(address);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFlushComplete(int requestCode) {
        LocationListener.super.onFlushComplete(requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        LocationListener.super.onProviderEnabled(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        LocationListener.super.onProviderDisabled(provider);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si pruebas en un emulador probablemente no podrás obtener la latitud/ longitud, a menos que la definas manualmente.

---

Si estás usando un dispositivo fisico, te sugiero realices el siguiente cambio para validación de permisos, únicamente si se tienen los permisos que se llame `mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates()` al tener permisos hay que revisar si los proveedores se encuentran activos:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    //*Existen permisos, activa geolocalización
    //Pero antes, Obtiene status de los proveedores.
    boolean gps_enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean network_enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (gps_enabled) {
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000 /*1 minuto*/ , 1 /*1 metro*/ , (LocationListener) Local);
        mensaje1.setText("Localización Agregada GPS_PROVIDER...");
        mensaje2.setText("");
    } else if (network_enabled) {
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000 /*1 minuto*/ , 1 /*1 metro*/ , (LocationListener) Local);
        mensaje1.setText("Localización Agregada NETWORK_PROVIDER...");
        mensaje2.setText("");

    } else {
        Log.e("ERROR", "No existe un proveedor activo");
    }


} else {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Permisos no aceptados.");
}
```

---

Recuerda que es importante no definir valores de 0 para:

`minTimeMs`: intervalo de tiempo mínimo entre actualizaciones de ubicación en milisegundos
`minDistanceM`: distancia mínima entre actualizaciones de ubicación en metros

ya que esto también puede ser causa del problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, adicionalmente añadí el siguiente bloque de código en cada uno de los else  de error: 

      Log.e("ERROR", "Permisos no aceptados.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

De esta forma ahora me está solicitando activar los permisos de ubicación, lo único malo es que aún no me funciona del todo. Ya que aún se queda congelado, obteniendo la ubicación GPS. Aunque en este punto quizás sea problema de mi celular

Comment: pd: perdona por no poder darte el +1 en tu respuesta, aun no tengo la reputación suficiente, nuevamente gracias

Comment: @Cristian gracias Cristian, espero tengas más participación en el sitio para que obtengas más reputación, saludos!